# Python's msvcrt.getch() behaves strangely: More than one char is got and stored from the stdin; resulting value is not even of type string or char

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, msvcrt, getch

```
from msvcrt import getch

print ("go: ")
test = getch()

print(test)
```

then, my console interactions:

```
>python -i testdirin.py
go: ## here I input the number 3 from the keyboard
b'3'
>>> print(test)
b'3'
>>> test == '3'
False
>>> test == 3
False
>>> test == "b'3'"
False
>>> test == b'3'
True
>>>
```

As you can see, the variable `test` apparently evaluates to something that isn't even a string.
The same behaviour is replicated when I input a char (or anything other than an integer, really...) also.

Now, I can of course manipulate the stored value with `str(test)` and then extract the character that I need, but that's kinda entirely beyond the point of `getch()`.

So... what's going on here?

Comment: That's a bytestring, containing a single character (which is in an unspecified encoding rather than Unicode, and therefore isn't suitable for a normal `str`).  Typing `print(type(test))` would have been a good way to see exactly what you had.

Comment: That is certainly helpful information, although it doesn't exactly answer my question, which is why getch() deviates from the expected behaviour that is outlined in the msvcrt module's Documentation.

Comment: The documentation for that function looks like it hasn't been updated since the Python 2.x days.  You should probably be using `getwch()` instead, to directly get a Unicode character.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to do the trick. 
Now how do I mark your response as the one that solved my issue? :)

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow it up with a `type(b'3')` you get `<class 'bytes'>`

You could, apply method `.decode()` on it and will return a string

Or, do `chr(char_received[0])` where `char_received` is `b'3'`